# Javascript if else condition run time failure

Tags: javascript

I have started javascript today. Trying with the very basic and got stuck with If Else loop.

```
    var input = prompt("type your name"); //variable stores the value user inputs
    var outout = tostring(input); // the input value is changed to string datatype and    stored in var output
    alert(output);//supposed to display the value which it doesn't

    if(output == "Tiger")
    {alert("It is dangerous");
    }
    Else
    {alert("all is well");
    }//I only get a blank page
```

If I omit the line var output = tostring(input) and try to display the alert box with input value I get the alert box. But after that I only get a blank page. The If Else loop doesn't work at all. I am using notepad++. Also checked in Dreamweaver. There is no compile error. What am I doing wrong?
Sorry for such a basic question and thanks for replying.

Regards,
TD

Comment: Javascript keywords and identifiers are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has the following problems:

```
var input = prompt("type your name");
var outout = tostring(input);
// Typo: outout should be output
// tostring() is not a function as JavaScript is case-sensitive
// I think you want toString(), however in this context
// it is the same as calling window.toString() which is going to
// return an object of some sort. I think you mean to call
// input.toString() which, if input were not already a string
// (and it is) would return a string representation of input.
alert(output);
// displays window.toString() as expected.
if(output == "Tiger")
{alert("It is dangerous");
}
Else    // JavaScript is case-sensitive: you need to use "else" not "Else"
{alert("all is well");
}//I only get a blank page
```

I suspect what you want is this:

```
var input = prompt("type your name");
alert(input);
if (input === "Tiger") {
    alert("It is dangerous");
} else {
    alert("all is well");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Pete for replying. Outout was a Typo. It works now after I omitted the <<var output = toString(input);>>. I do not have a programming background so sorry to disappoint you guys on silly mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Your line

`tostring(input);`

Should be

`toString(input);`

The `toString()` method has a capital S

Also, your output variable is called "outout". Don't know if that's a typo...

Not only that, your `Else` should also have a small `e`. All JavaScript keywords are case sensitive.

Comment: @Doorknob just noticed. Thanks for the +1 :)

Comment: Also, `toString()` is an instance method.

Comment: I neglected the case sensitive part...changed tostring to toString and the 2nd alert box comes up. But I am not sure what is instance method...I do not have a programming background. Sorry for the negligence. Thanks a lot for the reply.

Comment: @user1976929 if ive helped, please consider accepting my answer (the green tick under the upvote/downvote counter).

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to convert the result of a prompt to a string, it is a string already. And it actually would be

```
input.toString()
```

And `Else` is lowercase, the correct would be `else`.

So you can use like this

```
var input = prompt("Type your name");

if (input == "Tiger")
{
    alert("Wow, you are a Tiger!");
}
else
{
    alert("Hi " + input);
}
```

Notice that if you type `tiger` (lowercase) you will end up on the `else`. If you want to compare a string case insensitive you can do this:

```
if (input.toLowerCase() == "tiger")
```

Then even `tIgEr` will work.

Comment: I omitted the  var outout = toString(input); and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: .toString and Convert.toString()....could you please explain what is the difference?..thanks.

Comment: There isn't `Convert.toString` in javascript. Do you mean C# `Convert.ToString()`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tostring.aspx

Comment: BrunoLM that was my misunderstanding.Sorry.But still confused if the correct one is variable.toString or toString(variable). Thanks for replying.

Comment: You should use `var.toString()` which will always return a value of `string` type